# Filter on folder and item type in ArcGIS Online

Tags: python-3.x, arcgis, querying

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvFKU.png)I want to change the extent of all webmaps in a given folder in ArcGIS Online. However, the standard query command (gis.content.search) does not have a property that allows searching only in a folder.
On the other hand, once I have a list of all items in a given folder, I am unable to only filter all webmaps out. This is the script I used (see also the image):

```
folderowner = 'my_username'
updatefolder = 'testfolder'

user = gis.user.get(username=my_username)
user

rightFolder = user.items(folder = updatefolder)
rightFolder

for item in rightFolder:
    print(item.type)

for item in rightFolder:
    if (item_type = "Web Map"):
        print (item.title)
```

[screenshot of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4YYM.png)
I can print the Item types. But once I try to list only Web Maps, I get a Syntax error. I have tried many different notations.

I can pass the types in a print command, but I can't use the types as a way to filter. Where I am basically looking for is thus a way to get only web maps in a given folder.

Comment: When doing a comparison, you need 2 == signs. `if item_type == "Web Map":`

Comment: Of course... thanks!